# C# - Async Task<T> method - Am I doing the implementation right with ConfigureAwait?

Tags: c#

I have an async `Task<string>` method when called without `ConfigureAwait`, it causes deadlock and the string is not returned. But when I added `ConfigureAwait`, it works as expected.

```
   public async Task<string> TestConnectionAsync()
    {
        string str = "";
        await Task<string>.Run(() =>
        {
            //do stuff and assign to str variable here
          
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return str;
    }
```

My question is: Is this the proper way of writing an async method or this can be improved further?

Comment: `it causes deadlock`.  This is probably due to the calling code up the stack.

Comment: The entire use of `Task.Run` is unnecessary; there are native async methods you can use. i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection.openasync?view=net-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#System_Data_Common_DbConnection_OpenAsync. Plus, the semantics of the method are a bit odd. I'd expect this to return a `bool` -- `true` if it can connect, `false` if it can't.

Comment: I am aware of the native async methods for SqlConnection but what I am asking for is for general async methods.

Comment: @Joseph If you have a question about a *specific* scenario that's failing, post the code for that scenario. The solution to the question given the code you provided is "use the native async methods".

Answer (score 0):

I would say your code looks good. You are using the correct methods and awaits where appropriate. Overall a solid implementation.

If you want to improve it, consider adding a `CancellationToken` to your task.

```
public async Task<string> TestConnectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    string str = "";
    await Task<string>.Run(() =>
    {
        ...
    }, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return str;
}
```

If this is being called from an API endpoint simply add:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult MyFunc(CancellationToken cancellationToken){
    // Pass it down
    TestConnectionAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

And keep passing it down. The cancellationToken is Auto generated.

if it is from something like Blazor or somewhere else you can use this implementation:

```
using (var source = new CancellationSource()){
    TestConnectionAsync(source.Token);
}
```

### Where would this actually be used?

Dynamic filters on web-pages is a greate use of CancellationTokens. Say everytime you type a letter it goes to the database and searched through a list of cases mathcing the string.

Now if you type a word like 'Sports Equipment', it will make 16 calls to the backend and database. Without a `CancellationToken` it will load all the data 16 times. A huge resource expenditure. However, with a cancellationToken it will cancel the data load request with each button press so you don't get 16 loads but rather 1 (and some cancelled ones).

Comment: Thank you. Guess this is what I am looking for.

Comment: No problem, I added an example of where it is appropriate to use.

Answer (score 0):

The `TestConnectionAsync` method violates the guideline for [not exposing asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/).

> The only asynchronous methods that should be exposed are those that have scalability benefits over their synchronous counterparts. Asynchronous methods should not be exposed purely for the purpose of offloading: such benefits can easily be achieved by the consumer of synchronous methods using functionality specifically geared towards working with synchronous methods asynchronously, e.g. `Task.Run`.

Another weak pattern is relying on side-effects for propagating the result. Instead of `//do stuff and assign to str variable here` it should be `//do stuff and return the string result`. The result can then be obtained organically by awaiting the task:

```
string str = await Task.Run(() => TestConnection());
```

Comment: So the article means it's better to use public Task<string> then wrap the implementation inside Task.Run than use public async Task<string>?

Comment: @Joseph it's better to expose a synchronous API: `public string TestConnection()`. The callers, if they want, can easily offload it to the `ThreadPool` by wrapping it into a `Task.Run`.

Comment: I see. so it's better to have synchronous methods in a library and not bother write an async version of it?

Comment: @Joseph yeap, that's what Microsoft recommends. And the reasoning is quite solid.

Comment: To be precise, you shouldn't bother writing async versions of an API, unless you are able to provide it with a truly asynchronous implementation. Which means that [no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) should be blocked while the operation is in-flight. If you can't do that, it's recommended to stick with the synchronous API.